# How to display numbers greater than the mean in a list?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, int, sum

I have tried a few different thing here and I'm just at a lost.  Any help would be appreciated, here is my code.

```
numL = [];
for count in range (6):
    num = input("Enter Numbers ");
    if int(num) <= -999:
        print("Sentinel value was entered")
print(int(num) > sum(int(num))/ float(len(int(num))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 3.4 you can use [statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) and a list comp:

```
from statistics import  mean

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print([x for x in l if x > mean(l)])
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Not sure what your if statement is doing but you could just create a list if nums when you get the input:

```
nums = [int(input("Enter Numbers ")) for _ in range(6)]
print([x for x in nums if x > mean(nums)])
```

Comment: I am using 3.4, but I tried implementing this into my code and I get can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator, so I tried converting it to an int, but no luck.

Comment: @underspych, try the code I just added, I am not fully sure what you if should be doing or the later code as you have ints not a list so len() etc.. makes no sense

Comment: Hey the only problem I'm having now was in my original code I had

if int(num) <= -999:
        print("Sentinel value was entered")

now that does not work at all I tried converting the list into an int but no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to easily accomplish this:

```
[a for a in your_list if a > sum(your_list) / len(your_list)]
```

If you're not familiar with list comprehensions, this basically says:

> for every element `a` in `your_list`, add `a` to a new list if it's greater than the sum of the list divided by its length (i.e. its mean). Return the new list.

For example, for the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, this returns `[6, 7, 8, 9]`.